# how to make validation more than one field in laravel?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

How to validate more than one field in laravel? for example: I want corporate_id, brand_id or hotel_id not to have the same catalog name. that is, hotel_id 1 cannot have 2 catalog names "Default".

how to make such validation in laravel? thank you

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far?? what is your current code structure?? it will be easy to answer knowing your code base.

Comment: oo, this is my controller tanyakoding.com/s/d1 and view tanyakoding.com/s/d2

Comment: don't just add picture..update your question with code as code.

Comment: catalog name??? what do you mean by that?

Comment: sorry, the catalog name is the data in the title field.

Comment: you have to use condition for validation. like the switch case you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Custom Validation Rules.
It's easy to handle
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-rule-objects

```
/**
 * Determine if the validation rule passes.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  array  $value
 * @return bool
 */
public function passes($attribute, $catalogName)
{
    $catalog = Catalog::where('title', $catalogName);
    // corporate_id, brand_id or hotel_id 
    if (Input::get('corporate_id')) {
       $catalog->where('corporate_id', Input::get('corporate_id'));
    }
    if (Input::get('brand_id')) {
       $catalog->where('brand_id', Input::get('brand_id'));
    }
    if (Input::get('hotel_id')) {
       $catalog->where('corporate_id', Input::get('hotel_id'));
    }

    if ($catalog->first()) { 
       return false; 
    }
    else {
       return true;
    }

}
```